# Attempting to scale a dataframe (X_train) with MinMaxScaler(). Throwing ValueError : array shape = (0,) minimum of 1 is required

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, classification, preprocessor, one-hot-encoding

In order to pre-process my data, I am attempting to transform a binary classifier. All parts work fine individually, but when put into a function, the value error: Found array with 0 sample (s) (shape = (0,)) while a minimum of 1 is required is thrown.

X_train data after OneHotEncoding:

```
0   0.66    759.5   318.5   220.50  3.5 2   0.40    3   1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
1   0.76    661.5   416.5   122.50  7.0 3   0.10    1   0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0
2   0.66    759.5   318.5   220.50  3.5 3   0.10    1   0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0
3   0.74    686.0   245.0   220.50  3.5 5   0.10    4   0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0
4   0.64    784.0   343.0   220.50  3.5 2   0.40    4   1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
609 0.98    514.5   294.0   110.25  7.0 4   0.40    2   0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0
610 0.90    563.5   318.5   122.50  7.0 3   0.10    1   0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0
611 0.82    612.5   318.5   147.00  7.0 4   0.25    2   0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0
612 0.71    710.5   269.5   220.50  3.5 5   0.10    1   0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0
613 0.64    784.0   343.0   220.50  3.5 2   0.25    5   1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
```

The function I am attempting to use

```
def feature_engineering(data):
    data = data[(np.nan_to_num(np.abs(stats.zscore(data, nan_policy='omit')),0) < 3).all(axis=1)]
    data = data[(np.nan_to_num(np.abs(stats.zscore(data, nan_policy='omit')),0) > 3).all(axis=1)]
    csc = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore').fit_transform(data[['orientation']])
    ob = pd.DataFrame(data=csc.toarray(), columns=["o1", "o2", "o3", "o4"])
    ob = csc.reshape((ob,614*12))
    data = pd.concat([data, ob], axis = 1)
    scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
    X_train = scaler.fit_transform(data)


data = pd.DataFrame(feature_engineering(X_train))
X_eval = pd.DataFrame(feature_engineering(X_eval))
```

The traceback error

```
-------------------------------------------------- ------------------------- 
ValueError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-51-d0f1271d1165> in <module> 
     11  
     12  # 
- -> 13  data = pd . DataFrame ( feature_engineering ( X_train ) ) 
     14 X_eval = pd . DataFrame ( feature_engineering ( X_eval ) )

<ipython-input-51-d0f1271d1165> in feature_engineering (data) 
      3      data = data [ ( np . nan_to_num ( np . abs ( stats . zscore ( data , nan_policy = ' omit ' ) ) , 0 )  <  3 ) . all ( axis = 1 ) ] 
      4      data = data [ ( np .nan_to_num ( np . abs ( stats . zscore ( data , nan_policy = ' omit ' ) ) , 0 )  >  3 ) . all ( axis = 1 ) ] 
----> 5      csc = OneHotEncoder ( handle_unknown = 'ignore' ) . fit_transform ( data [ [ 'orientation' ] ] ) 
      6      ob= pd . DataFrame ( data = csc . Toarray ( ) , columns = [ "o1" ,  "o2" ,  "o3" ,  "o4" ] ) 
      7      ob = csc . reshape ( ( ob , 614 * 12 ) )

~ \ anaconda3 \ lib \ site-packages \ sklearn \ preprocessing \ _encoders.py in fit_transform (self, X, y) 
    408          "" "
     409          self . _validate_keywords ( ) 
-> 410 return super ( ) . fit_transform ( X , y )     411     412 def transform ( self , X ) :         
 
     

~ \ anaconda3 \ lib \ site-packages \ sklearn \ base.py in fit_transform (self, X, y, ** fit_params) 
    688          if y is  None : 
    689              # fit method of arity 1 (unsupervised transformation) 
-> 690 return self . fit ( X , ** fit_params ) . transform ( X )     691 else :     692 # fit method of arity 2 (supervised transformation)              
         
             

~ \ anaconda3 \ lib \ site-packages \ sklearn \ preprocessing \ _encoders.py in fit (self, X, y) 
    383          "" "
     384          self . _validate_keywords ( ) 
-> 385          self . _fit ( X , handle_unknown = self . handle_unknown ) 
    386          self . drop_idx_ = self . _compute_drop_idx ( ) 
    387          return self

~ \ anaconda3 \ lib \ site-packages \ sklearn \ preprocessing \ _encoders.py in _fit (self, X, handle_unknown) 
     72  
     73      def _fit ( self , X , handle_unknown = 'error' ) : 
---> 74          X_list , n_samples , n_features = self . _check_X ( X ) 
     75  
     76          if self . categories ! =  'auto' :

~ \ anaconda3 \ lib \ site-packages \ sklearn \ preprocessing \ _encoders.py in _check_X (self, X) 
     58          for i in range ( n_features ) : 
     59              Xi = self . _get_feature ( X , feature_idx = i ) 
---> 60              Xi = check_array (Xi, ensure_2d = False, dtype = None,
      61                               force_all_finite = needs_validation)
      62              X_columns . append ( Xi )

~ \ anaconda3 \ lib \ site-packages \ sklearn \ utils \ validation.py in inner_f (* args, ** kwargs) 
     70                            FutureWarning)
      71          kwargs . update ( { k : arg for k , arg in zip ( sig . parameters , args ) } ) 
---> 72 return f ( ** kwargs )      73 return inner_f
      74         
      

~ \ anaconda3 \ lib \ site-packages \ sklearn \ utils \ validation.py in check_array (array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, -dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, estimator) 
    648          N_SAMPLES = _num_samples ( array ) 
    649          if n_samples < ensure_min_samples : 
-> 650              raise ValueError ("Found array with% d sample (s) (shape =% s) while a"
     651                               "minimum of% d is required% s." 
    652                               % (n_samples, array.shape, ensure_min_samples,

ValueError : Found array with 0 sample (s) (shape = (0,)) while a minimum of 1 is required.
```

X_train['orientation']:

```
0 2
1 3
2 3
3 5
4 2
      ..
609 4
610 3
611 4
612 5
```

Comment: It seems you are feeding the OneHotEncoder with 0 samples. Can you print what are you trying to onehot?: `data[['orientation']]` . The error should be here.

Comment: Printed Sir, so much respect to anyone who knows their way around ML!

Comment: To find the mistake, try to run the first three lines of the function one by one. But do it outside the function and printing every time the output. In one step, you should obtain empty dataframe.